# Pass object id to view from form submission

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a website where user submitted entries are displayed and have an `upvote` count along with a button to upvote it yourself. These are represented with the `Entry` model. How do I pass the id of the particular `Entry` instance the user upvotes to a view?

html:

```
{% for entry in entries %}

<div id="upvote_count">
  <form action="upvote" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ entry.upvotes }}
    <button id="upvote" type="submit">Upvote</button>
  </form>
</div>

    {% endfor %}
```

models.py:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    #... 
    upvotes = models.IntegerField( blank = True, null=True)
```

current url:

```
url(r'^upvote$', views.upvote),
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, how would the `upvote` view be aware of `entry.id`?

Comment: inside your `for entry in entries` loop, if you can access `entry.upvotes`, I assume you can also access `entry.id`?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it inside a hidden `input`, such as:

```
<form ...>
...
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ entry.id }}">
<button ...>
</form>
```

and access to it in your view:

```
def upvote(request):
    entry_id = int(request.GET.get("id"))
    ...
```